# Node.js MYSQL escaping query values for between clause

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I am working on a query and it works fine in HeidiSQL fine, but its null when am trying to pass variable values into it via escape string.

I am already doing this for some past functionality but I am unsure if it is possible or even a alternative when using the between clause.

***SQL (Runs how I want it)***

```
SELECT cnam,
SUM(CASE WHEN disposition = "Answered" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Answered,
SUM(CASE WHEN disposition = "No Answer" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS NotAnswered,
SUM(CASE WHEN disposition = "Busy" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Busy,
SUM(CASE WHEN disposition = "Failed" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Failed
FROM cdr 
WHERE cnam NOT LIKE '+%' 
AND calldate BETWEEN DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 7 DAY AND DATE(NOW())
GROUP BY cnam;
```

***Node.js MySQL Code(Null being returned)***

```
var startdate = 'DATE(NOW())  - INTERVAL 7 DAY';
var enddate = 'DATE(NOW())';

  function SQLReportAgentCalls() {
    valueArrAgentDipo = [];
    connection2.query({
      sql : 'SELECT cnam,\
              SUM(CASE WHEN disposition = "Answered" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Answered,\
              SUM(CASE WHEN disposition = "No Answer" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS NotAnswered,\
              SUM(CASE WHEN disposition = "Busy" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Busy,\
              SUM(CASE WHEN disposition = "Failed" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Failed\
              FROM cdr \
              WHERE cnam NOT LIKE "+%" \
              AND calldate BETWEEN ? AND ?\
              GROUP BY cnam;',
      timeout : 40000,
      values : [startdate, enddate]
    }, function (error, results, rows, fields) {
  if (err) {
    throw err;
  } else {
    console.log(results);
  }
    });
  }
```

Am I looking at or doing something wrong, or is it not possible or even a workaround.

**CALLBACK:** Only values being returned when am logging `error` and `result` is, `error` returns null and `results` returns []. Telling me there is not errors but the it got nothing from the DB which I believe is because of escaping of the values, **if I hard-code in those query's stored in variables it works fine**.

But if I want to change those dates to change those parameters it becomes an issue.

Comment: Is there anything in `error`  or `results`?

Comment: @OscarGonzalez Nothing, only values being returned when am logging them is `error` returns null and `results` returns []. Telling me there is not errors but the it got nothing from the DB which I believe is because of escaping of the values, if I hardcode in those query's it works fine.

Comment: try logging query which is being returned by mysql npm in callback function. function(error, results, rows, fields, pQuery)

Comment: @Mannu tried logging the query using the following `function (error, results, rows, fields,SQLReportAgentCalls) {
if (err){
        throw err;
      }
      else{
             console.log(results); 
        }` and results gets returned as `[]` there because there's an issue with escaping the query values and the between clause I think.

Comment: Perhaps try either string concatenation or template literals: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals